# ML.NET Examples - Sales Forescasting - Why are previous and next day's amounts included in current day?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression, ml.net

Looking at the examples for ML.NET, I can see that they augment the original data source

```
InvoiceNo: Invoice number. Nominal, a 6-digit integral number uniquely assigned to each transaction. If this code starts with letter 'c', it indicates a cancellation.
StockCode: Product (item) code. Nominal, a 5-digit integral number uniquely assigned to each distinct product.
Description: Product (item) name. Nominal.
Quantity: The quantities of each product (item) per transaction. Numeric.
InvoiceDate: Invice Date and time. Numeric, the day and time when each transaction was generated.
UnitPrice: Unit price. Numeric, Product price per unit in sterling.
CustomerID: Customer number. Nominal, a 5-digit integral number uniquely assigned to each customer.
Country: Country name. Nominal, the name of the country where each customer resides.
```

with some extra properties such as

```
next : next month units sold
prev : previous month units sold
max : max items sold in a day of month
min : min items sold in a day of month
avg : average of items sold per day
```

to train their models for sales forecasting. Why do they add the `next`,`prev`, `avg`, `min` and `max` properties to each row?

[Details of Dataset](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/blob/main/samples/csharp/end-to-end-apps/Forecasting-Sales/docs/Details-of-Dataset.md)

[ML Sample](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/main/samples/csharp/end-to-end-apps/Forecasting-Sales?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website)